# AWS CLI search through tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I want to filter multiple tags on AWS CLI.
I have something like this:
`aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[*]'`
this command gives me all my tags on instances.

I have like 900 instances and 30 tags for each of them.
What I'm trying to do is
1)Sort by three tag:
`"Key:a && Key:b && Key:c"`
2) After I get Key I want to search for value too:
`"Key:a, Value:x && Key:b, Value=y && Key:c, Value=Z"`
Basically, I need to search through these instances by tag name from CLI.

Comment: What is your question? What do you mean by "search through these instances by tag name"? Are you asking how to do this using the AWS CLI? I would instead recommend that you use an AWS SDK (eg boto3 for Python) to retrieve the information and sort/search the data. It would be much simpler than attempting to do this via shell scripts.

Comment: So, you need to filter only instances having the tags `a == x and b == y and c == z`, is that it?

Comment: I want to search for instances by filtering tag @JohnRotenstein I will take a look at boto3 for python, Thanks!

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε yes that is what exactly I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to filter by tags so that the response only contains instances with those tags, you can add more `--filters`:

```
--filters Name=instance-state-name,Values=running Name=tag:a,Values=x Name=tag:b,Values=y Name=tag:c,Values=z
```